# How to print UTF-8 symbols by entering decimal number?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example I enter decimal number 210 that is symbol "Ò".

For example code

```
int a = 210;
wcout << wchar_t (a);
```

works fine, but before "wcout" I use "cout" and they are not compatible.

```
int main() {
  string a = "\u";
  string b = "210";
  string c = a + b;
  cout << b + a << endl;
  cout << "Second cout message...";
}
```

ERROR:

```
main.cpp:4:15: error: \u used with no
      following hex digits
  string a = "\u";
              ^~
1 error generated.
compiler exit status 1
```

Comment: You cannot have a literal hanging. Literals are parsed by the compiler, and it will insert actual characters in place of literal.

Comment: You need to encode any value greater than 127 into UTF-8. There are rules about how many high bits are set which control how many bytes are used and where the value bits go.

Comment: Although wcout is fancier than just UTF-8. I believe the C and C++ runtime libraries will encode wide characters into whatever the standard output encoding is.

Comment: What is your OS and compiler?

Comment: Escape sequences are processed at compile time, not run time. An escape sequence must be entirely contained in one literal; it cannot span across adjacent literals, even though they are merged into one object, as in `"\u" "\210"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::wcrtomb` to convert wide character to multi byte string. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcrtomb

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwchar>
#include <clocale>

int main() {
  std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
  wchar_t wc = 127820;
  char mbstr[5]{};
  std::mbstate_t state{};
  std::wcrtomb(mbstr, wc, &state);
  std::cout << mbstr << std::endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/QVMppe

Also if you are interested in what Unicode is and how it is encoded with variable width character encoding, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: This will work fine on (most) systems where `wchar_t` is 32 bits in size, or the number entered is <= `0xFFFF`.  But on systems where `wchar_t` is 16 bits (ie Windows), this will not work for numbers > `0xFFFF` (outside the BMP). You would have to use `std::wcsrtombs()` (or equivalent) with 2 `wchar_t`s as input (UTF-16) instead. Personally, I would just encode the UTF-8 manually, since it a very straight-forward algorithm to manually convert a 32-bit Unicode codepoint number into a UTF-8 byte sequence.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is very easy to encode manually, eg:

```cpp
std::string toUTF8(uint32_t cp)
{
    char utf8[4];
    int len = 0;

    if (cp <= 0x007F)
    {
        utf8[0] = static_cast<char>(cp);
        len = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (cp <= 0x07FF)
        {
            utf8[0] = 0xC0;
            len = 2;
        }
        else if (cp <= 0xFFFF)
        {
            utf8[0] = 0xE0;
            len = 3;
        }
        else if (cp <= 0x10FFFF)
        {
            utf8[0] = 0xF0;
            len = 4;
        }
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("invalid codepoint");

        for(int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
        {
            utf8[len-i] = static_cast<char>(0x80 | (cp & 0x3F));
            cp >>= 6;
        }

        utf8[0] |= static_cast<char>(cp);
    }

    return std::string(utf8, len);
}

int main()
{
    std::string utf8 = toUTF8(210);
    std::cout << utf8;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/8QAJip)

Make sure your console actually supports displaying UTF-8 text.